# Does OpenCV offer a squared norm function for cv::Point?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have to check several distances between points against a distance threshold. What I can do is taking the square of my threshold and compare it with the squared norm of `(a-b)`, where `a` and `b` are the points I am checking.

I know about [`cv::norm`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#norm) function, but I wonder if there exists a version that doesn't compute the square root (and therefore is faster) or if I should implement it manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>**Note from [OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146514/225842):**
I accepted this answer as it's the best method one can achieve using OpenCV,
but I think the best solution in this case is going for a custom function.</sub>

---

Yes, it's `NORM_L2SQR`:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<Point> pts{ Point(0, 2) };

    double n = norm(pts, NORM_L2SQR);
    // n is 4

    return 0;
}
```

You can see in the function `cv::norm` in `stat.cpp` that if you use `NORM_L2SQR` you don't compute the `sqrt` on the norm:

```
...
if( normType == NORM_L2 )
{
    double result = 0;
    GET_OPTIMIZED(normL2_32f)(data, 0, &result, (int)len, 1);
    return std::sqrt(result);
}
if( normType == NORM_L2SQR )
{
    double result = 0;
    GET_OPTIMIZED(normL2_32f)(data, 0, &result, (int)len, 1);
    return result;
}
...
```

---

Regarding the specific issue:

> My actual problem is: I have a vector of points, merge points closer to each other than a given distance. "Merging" means remove one and move the other half way towards the just removed point.

You can probably

- take advantage of the [partition](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/clustering.html#partition) function with a predicate that returns `true` if two points are within a given threshold.
- retrieve all points in the same cluster
- compute the centroid for each cluster

Here the code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<Point> pts{ Point(0, 2), Point{ 1, 0 }, Point{ 10, 11 }, Point{11,12}, Point(2,2) };

    // Partition according to a threshold
    int th2 = 9;
    vector<int> labels;     
    int n = partition(pts, labels, [th2](const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) { 
        return ((lhs.x - rhs.x)*(lhs.x - rhs.x) + (lhs.y - rhs.y)*(lhs.y - rhs.y)) < th2;
    });

    // Get all the points in each partition
    vector<vector<Point>> clusters(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < pts.size(); ++i)
    {
        clusters[labels[i]].push_back(pts[i]);
    }

    // Compute the centroid for each cluster
    vector<Point2f> centers;
    for (const vector<Point>& cluster : clusters)
    {
        // Compute centroid
        Point2f c(0.f,0.f);
        for (const Point& p : cluster)
        {
            c.x += p.x;
            c.y += p.y;
        }
        c.x /= cluster.size();
        c.y /= cluster.size();

        centers.push_back(c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

will produce the two centers:

```
centers[0] : Point2f(1.0, 1.3333);
centers[1] : Point2f(10.5, 11.5)
```

Comment: I don't know actually. Just looking through source code... I see if I find a documentation for this...

Comment: Uhm, this requires creating a vector looks overkill.

Comment: That was just for showing the usage. `cv::norm` accepts an `InputArray`. How are your points stored?

Comment: My actual problem is: I have a vector of points, merge points closer to each other than a given distance. "Merging" means remove one and move the other half way towards the just removed point. I need a plain `normL2Sqr` which takes one point as input.

Comment: Ok, so the actual problem is not the same as in the question I think... am I correct? If you update your question with the actual problem or create a new one probably you'll get a suited answer.

Comment: @Antonio I update the question with a reference to your actual problem. let me know if it works (and if it's faster the your custom implementation :D)

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but it's really much simpler than this, I haven't point clouds but just a few sparse points. I just need a function to compute the squared distance between 2 points or the squared norm of one point, that's all.

Comment: @Antornio Well, still it was a nice opportunity to learn how to use `partition` :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's nothings specific to address this problem.

I thought that one solution could be using the `ddot` method (dot product), and compute something like

```
cv::Point distVec = a-b;
double squaredNorm = distVec.ddot(distVec);
```

If one is willing to take the risk, there's `cv::normL2Sqr` which requires the input to be in array format: `cv::Point` might be directly convertible to `int[]`.

I will personally move on by writing my own squared norm.