# OpenCV squared norm for cv::Point2d

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to use squared euclidean norm `cv::NORM_L2SQR` without taking root, as shown here

[Does OpenCV offer a squared norm function for cv::Point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32887671)

to save computational resources. So while the following code works:

```
// works fine 
cv::Point2d a(1.5, 3);
cv::Point2d b(5.1, 6);
//Euclidean distance
//http://answers.opencv.org/question/14188
double res = cv::norm(a-b);
```

The following doesn't:

```
double res = cv::norm(a-b,cv::NORM_L2SQR);
```

(`error: no matching function for call to norm(cv::Point_<double>, cv::NormTypes)`)

What can I do in OpenCV 3.1 to use optimized solution?

EDIT: I'm using custom function at the moment and hope that compiler optimizes it somehow:

```
double euclideanDist(cv::Point2d& p, cv::Point2d& q) {
    cv::Point2d diff = p - q;
    return (diff.x*diff.x + diff.y*diff.y);
}
```

Comment: It seems that only Point2f are accepted (Point_<float>).  I should double check, though

Comment: @Miki Nope, I get "`no matching function`" even for Point2f

Comment: I guess you are overkilling it, There seems no huge performance improvements, etc to me for using OpenCV implementation instead of a simple C++ inline definition of a simple EqDist method, You may read the comments: http://answers.opencv.org/question/14188/calc-eucliadian-distance-between-two-single-point/?answer=14190#post-id-14190 to verify my assumptions

Comment: I checked. The easier and most efficient solution is to write your own function like your `euclideanDist`. I'll probably write an answer later explaining why (but I've not enough time right now...). Bottom-line: @ZdaR is right

Comment: @ZdaR , @Miki Well, I've checked the comments - maybe you're right, let it be then if there is no performance improvement. I'm not much familiar with low-leveI computation, so I just try to use native solutions when dealing with optimized libraries like OpenCV, try not to use loops, etc.  I thought that as long as these functions for different `Point` types seem to be templated, it is strange that there is no embedded solution for other norms like `NORM_L2SQR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to explicitly construct an InputArray container (e.g. matrix) in order to compile properly for non-default parameters:

`double res = cv::norm( cv::Mat( a0 - b0 ), cv::NORM_L2SQR );`

Though cost of creating a container object might be slower than just calculating the norm.

`cv::norm( std::vector< cv::Point2d >( 1, a0 - b0 ), cv::NORM_L2SQR );`

Perhaps converting Point2d to std::complex and using the std::norm() is more thoughtful.

```
cv::Point2d diff = a0 - b0;
std::norm( std::complex< double >( diff.x, diff.y ) );
```