# OpenCV + Python: Calculate stereo reprojection error

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I want to do something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781089/opencv-calibratecamera-2-reprojection-error-and-custom-computed-one-not-agree), but for `stereoCalibrate()` instead of `calibrateCamera()`. That is, compute the reprojection error for a stereo camera calibration.

My reduced example looks like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def calibrate_stereo(w, h, objpoints, imgpoints_l, imgpoints_r):
    stereocalib_criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS , 1000, 1e-6)
    retval, A1, D1, A2, D2, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(objpoints,imgpoints_l, imgpoints_r,None,None,None,None, (w,h), flags=0, criteria=stereocalib_criteria)

    return (retval, (A1,D1,A2,D2, R, T, E, F))

def calc_rms_stereo(objectpoints, imgpoints_l, imgpoints_r, A1, D1, A2, D2, R, T):
    tot_error = 0
    total_points = 0

    for i, objpoints in enumerate(objectpoints):
        # calculate world <-> cam1 transformation
        _, rvec_l, tvec_l,_ = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objpoints, imgpoints_l[i], A1, D1)

        # compute reprojection error for cam1
        rp_l, _ = cv2.projectPoints(objpoints, rvec_l, tvec_l, A1, D1)
        tot_error += np.sum(np.square(np.float64(imgpoints_l[i] - rp_l)))
        total_points += len(objpoints)

        # calculate world <-> cam2 transformation
        rvec_r, tvec_r  = cv2.composeRT(rvec_l,tvec_l,cv2.Rodrigues(R)[0],T)[:2]

        # compute reprojection error for cam2
        rp_r,_ = cv2.projectPoints(objpoints, rvec_r, tvec_r, A2, D2)
        tot_error += np.square(imgpoints_r[i] - rp_r).sum()
        total_points += len(objpoints)

    mean_error = np.sqrt(tot_error/total_points)

    return mean_error


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    # omitted: reading values for w,h, objectPoints, imgpoints_l, imgpoints_r from file (format as expected by the OpenCV functions)
    # [...]

    rms, (A1,D1,A2,D2,R,T,_,_) = calibrate_stereo(w, h, objectpoints, imgpoints_l, imgpoints_r)

    print("RMS (stereo calib): {}".format(rms))

    rms_2 = calc_rms_stereo(objectpoints, imgpoints_l, imgpoints_r, A1, D1, A2, D2, R, T)    
    print("RMS (custom calculation):", rms_2)
```

Sample output:

```
RMS (stereo calib): 0.14342257926694932
RMS (custom calculation): 0.356273345751
```

As far as I can tell, the computation in the source code of `stereoCalibrate()` is very similar to mine. What am I missing?

OpenCV 3.3.0 on Ubuntu

Comment: What I understood of the source code of stereo calibrate they do the distance between the point ( norm(a-b) )  added to the error and then they divide and get the root square... I think you add the squares of all the points components difference and do square root... Maybe I am wrong

Comment: @api55 that's what i thought too. I assume you mean [this line](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blame/master/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp#L2152), but they are indeed using a [square norm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32887671/does-opencv-offer-a-squared-norm-function-for-cvpoint)

Comment: exactly that one. Also, it makes sense. RMSE is the root of the mean of the squared error, however it depends of what you define as error. As far as I know, the reprojection error is the distance of a point projected in 2D with a point in 2D used to generate the 3D point in the first place...

Comment: Yes, i agree. But norm(a-b)^2 (i.e. squared distance between points a & b) should be equal to the sum of the squared elementwise differences, i.e. (a[0]-b[0])^2 + (a[1]-b[1])^2 no?

Comment: Hmmm, actually it is true, I didn't see that they were using `NORM_L2SQR` which is the squared version..... then everything looks the same, strange... I do not spot the difference :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it after implementing a custom stereo calibration algorithm based on the OpenCV implementation.

The difference between the reprojection error calculated inside `cv2.stereoCalibrate()` and my custom calculation stems from different values for the extrinsic parameters `rvec_l` and `tvec_l`. These vectors describe the rotation and translation between the left camera and the calibration pattern for each image. `cv2.solvePnpRansac()` yields optimized values based only on the reprojection error of the left image, while in `cv2.stereoCalibrate()` those values are optimized together with `R` and `T` based on the reprojection error in both images of each stereo pair.

If one wants to exactly replicate the RMS value that is returned by `cv2.stereoCalibrate()`, one has to modify the C/C++ source code of `cv::stereoCalibrate()` to return the optimized extrinsic parameters as well (`cv::calibrateCamera()` does that already for monocular calibration).

Comment: I didn't get the point. From the error's perspective cv2.stereocalibrate is a better option it seems, however you are suggesting changing the code of the same. Can you please explain this.